# How to display a sliding animation in my endless runner using Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, phaser-framework

I am trying to make an endless runner game with Phaser 3. I have gotten him to run and jump, but I don't know how to make him slide(I think because the animation Run keeps on running in the update function) is there a way I can make him slide for some seconds then return to playing. Please any suggestions or answers would be greatly needed and accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `arcade` physics-engine, you could simply use `setAccelerationX`. The player could slide, when the keys are not more pressed. How much the sprite will "slides", would than depend on the `drag` *(intended friction)* you set. [Documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body#drag) *(on this page of the documentation, you can find more information to `acceleration`, `drag` and other used methods and/or properties)*

**Here a small demo, showcasing this:**

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 160,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 100 },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    }
}; 

var cursors;
var player;
var playerStateText;

function create () {
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    playerStateText = this.add.text(10,10, 'Playerstate: ???', {color: '#ffffff'});
    
    let ground = this.add.rectangle(-40, 120, 480, 50, 0xBAF0FF).setOrigin(0);
    player = this.add.rectangle(20, 20, 30, 30, 0xcccccc).setOrigin(0);
    
    ground = this.physics.add.existing(ground);
    ground.body.setImmovable(true);
    ground.body.allowGravity = false;
    
    player = this.physics.add.existing(player);
    
    // Just to be sure that the player doesn't get too fast
    player.body.setMaxSpeed(160); 
    
    // Tweak this value to define how far/long the player should slide
    player.body.setDrag(120, 0);
    
    this.physics.add.collider(player, ground);      
}

function update (){
    let currentState = 'Playerstate: running';
    if (cursors.left.isDown){
        player.body.setAccelerationX(-160);
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.body.setAccelerationX(160);
    }
    else {
        player.body.setAccelerationX(0);
        if(Math.abs(player.body.velocity.x) > 3) {
           currentState = 'Playerstate: sliding';
        } else if(Math.abs(player.body.velocity.y) > 3) {
           currentState = 'Playerstate: falling';
        } else {
           currentState = 'Playerstate: stopped';
        }
    }
    
    if(player.x > 400){
       player.x = -20;
    }
    
    if(player.x < -20){
       player.x = 400;
    }
    
    playerStateText.setText(currentState);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

You then could set the right animation depending on the current player action, the velocity, or other properties.

**Update:**

If you just want to show the different animation, without any special interaction or functionallity, you could just chain animations like explained in this example: http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/chained-animation

Just Chain the *Run* and *Slide* animation, and then they will always play in the correct order without changing your code. If you want to change the speed during the slide, that is abit more work.

***And** you can checkout/use [events of animation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.Events.html), so that you can take action on animation: **start, stop, complete, and more ...***.

**For example:** If the player should slide after landing, it could look something like this:

```
  player.on(Phaser.Animations.Events.ANIMATION_COMPLETE_KEY + 'jump', function (anims) {
       player.chain([ 'slide', 'run' ]);
   }, this);
```

Comment: I'm glad you suggested this, no doubt it doesn't work but I am trying to make it accessible for mobile and can't use the cursor. Is there another way to make it work on mobile.

Comment: @AceEnyioko sure you could use the `pointerdown` and `pointerup` or so, but it is difficult to say what is the best way without knowing your code(structure)

Comment: and depending on your game mechanic

Comment: Yes I could use that but I also have jumping animation to characterize its movement.

Comment: @AceEnyioko In your original question you said _"...  is there a way I can make him slide for some seconds then return to playing ..."_ what do you mean with this? after game over? after jumping? when should the player slide?

Comment: @AceEnyioko I update my answer with a different ideas, how you could solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, it worked out great and it's working just fine now. I used @Mohammad Maaz boolean and worked to some extent but yours finished the work. I really appreciate, looking forward to completing the game.

Answer (score 0):

Simply maybe you could use "let som=true; if(som==true){runnerfunction()}" and when the button to slide will be used "som=false"

Comment: I have used the boolean and set its functioning and it worked quite well for the sliding though not as I expected. When I jump, at it's jumping intervals sliding animation plays. I have scanned my code and still don't know what's wrong. In case you might need to know I set a set timeout function to play the sliding animation for some seconds then return to run animation(don't know if it's the problem).

Comment: You may need a boolean variable for sliding animation too, and for jump as well