# Using friction with tile maps in phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have been making a simple platformer using phaser 3. The level is designed with a tile map from an array and the only sprite is the player itself. When the player presses the right arrow key the x velocity of the player increases. What I would like to do is have friction between the ground and the player so that our player stops once they let go of the key. I know that you can do this with other sprites but can you do it with tilemaps?

Comment: depending which physics enine you are using (`arcade` or `matter`), and if you need want gliding, but checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257061/1679286

Comment: btw.: sprite and tilemap _"friction"_ works the same, since the friction part, has to do with the physics objects.

Comment: Yes I am using arcade physics. How would you access the tilemap physics body? (Ex. player.body.friction)

Answer (score 1):

With `arcade` physics it is abit difficult to do this *(or more or less impossible)*. I personally would fake the *friction* by setting a callback with the method `map.setTileLocationCallback`, this callback sets the drag of the player *(or if you have multiple layers, you could even define a layer for this case)*.

With `matter` physics engine it should be possible, checkout [this demo](http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/collision/matter-destroy-tile-bodies) and/or [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.TileBody.html).

**Here is a short Demo for `arcade` physics:**
In this small demo, the player is moved with the cursor-keys.
*(the player should slide less on the left side = more friction)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

let player;
let cursors;
let playerStateText;

let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 12 * 16,
    height: 6 * 16,
    zoom: 2,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity: { y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: { create, preload, update },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload () {
    this.load.image('mario-tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/super-mario.png');
}

function create () {
    playerStateText = this.add.text(10, 10, 'Playerstate: ???', {color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 10})
        .setDepth(10);
        
    // Load a map from a 2D array of tile indices
    let level = [
      [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
      [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
      [  0,  0, 0,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
      [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
      [ 35, 36, 37,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
      [ 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14 ]
    ];
    
    // When loading from an array, make sure to specify the tileWidth and tileHeight
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    
    let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('mario-tiles');
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
    
    map.setCollision([ 39, 14], true, true, layer);
    
    player = this.add.rectangle(10, 10, 8, 8, 0xffffff);
    this.physics.add.existing(player);
    
    player.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);  
    
    // Just to be sure that the player doesn't get too fast
    player.body.setMaxSpeed(160); 
    
    // Tweak this value to define how far/long the player should slide
    player.body.setDrag(120, 0);
    this.physics.add.collider(player, layer);
    
    map.setTileLocationCallback(0, 4, 6, 1,  _ => player.body.setDrag(1000, 0) )
    map.setTileLocationCallback(6, 4, 6, 1,  _ => player.body.setDrag(100, 0) )
    
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update(){
 let currentState = 'Playerstate: running';
    if (cursors.left.isDown){
        player.body.setAccelerationX(-160);
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.body.setAccelerationX(160);
    }
    else {
        player.body.setAccelerationX(0);
        if(Math.abs(player.body.velocity.x) > 3) {
           currentState = 'Playerstate: sliding';
        } else if(Math.abs(player.body.velocity.y) > 3) {
           currentState = 'Playerstate: falling';
        } else {
           currentState = 'Playerstate: stopped';
        }
    }
    
    if(player.x > 400){
       player.x = -20;
    }
    
    if(player.x < -20){
       player.x = 400;
    }
    
    playerStateText.setText(currentState);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```